# ngx-bootstrap bsValueChange being called repeatedly

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx bootstrap to display a date picker an an Angular 8 component.

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="startDate" class="form-control date-field"
    maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" #dpEffective="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker
    [bsConfig]="dateOptions" (bsValueChange)="setDate($event)"
    triggers="" autocomplete="off" />
```

When the user changes the date, the `setDate` method is first called with the correct date (the date the user entered) as the `$event` parameter, but will be called repeatedly from the template with the current date (client system date). Is this an intended behavior of `bsValueChange`? Is is possible to disable this?

Thanks

Comment: can you show code of setDate?